# Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I am making build of my project, but i am not able to make build because some errors accors like

```
dyld[42806]: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: <09986113-043E-33EF-8AE9-D34818E16FDC> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C3F03E0F-0E58-40A5-96F6-1CED2574404E/Ordo.app/Ordo
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C3F03E0F-0E58-40A5-96F6-1CED2574404E/Ordo.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C3F03E0F-0E58-40A5-96F6-1CED2574404E/Ordo.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C3F03E0F-0E58-40A5-96F6-1CED2574404E/Ordo.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C3F03E0F-0E58-40A5-96F6-1CED2574404E/Ordo.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C3F03E0F-0E58-40A5-96F6-1CED2574404E/Ordo.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C3F03E0F-0E58-40A5-96F6-1CED2574404E/Ordo.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

I have tried by removing all pods and import pods again in my project.
Also try remove individual pod and import it again, but the result is same.

I am looking for the solution so that i can make build of the project and able to run the application in my phone and upload it on TestFlight.